# How to typeset time duration of a song?

Tags: typography

I need to reference several times (eg. `2:30` - two minutes and thirty seconds) from a song for an assignment I am working on.

I have thought of using `$2$:$30$` because I thought using `2:30` would be incorrect.

Is my method of typesetting song duration correct or is there some other method that is?

Comment: Adding the `$` will set it in math font, rather than text font.  In many cases, they will be the same font.  For music, where math and equations seems distant from the application, I would think `2:30` would suffice (without the dollars).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, I see. So any set of numbers that are not related to mathematics not need be set in the mathematics font?

Comment: That's correct.  When in math mode, other things will apply, like italic variables and extra space inserted around math operators, as in `a+b versus $a+b$`.  But in your case, none of that is relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2:30 will be incorrect, because of a space added between `:` and  `30`. I suggest a macro with a syntax close to what one writes: it takes `2:30` or even `2: 30` or `2 : 30` as an argument and will print something like `Duration  2:30` and a correct spacing (a thin space on both sides of the colon). It requires the `etoolbox` and `xparse` packages.

In addition, if the time is, say 3:00, you just have to type 3, the 00 will be added. If the length is less than 1 minute, you just type :45, say.

I didn't implement the case of ragas, for which the length can be more than 1 h, but it would be easy to do :)

Here is an example with and without the macro:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{etoolbox, xparse}

\def\lgthname{Duration}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \lgth%
{ >{\SplitArgument {1}{:}} m }
{\lgthaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\lgthaux}{mm}
{\lgthname\quad\ifblank{#1}{0}{#1}\,:\,\IfNoValueTF{#2}{00}{#2}}

    \begin{document}

\sffamily
\lgth{2: 30} \qquad \lgth{: 45}\qquad\lgth{3}\\

Duration\quad2 : 30\\

Duration\quad2:30\\

\end{document}
```

[image]